# How can I colour numbers in terminal with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see I can color things using `colorama` and `termcolor`.

I'd like to color my numbers using Python formatters:

```
print("My value is %.2f" % value)
```

where the number is green if `value > 0` otherwise red.

What's the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: There are 48 answers to [Print in terminal with colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors) - wich ones did you try out?

Comment: Duplicated Question [Print in terminal with colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors)

Comment: Hold on - that isn't right. I already know how to color things in terminal. This is a question about string formatters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in terminal with colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything you can easier/better that colorama or custom wrapper (take a look for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors) for reference).

The reason is that python doesn't have great extensibility with string templates/formatting. Terminal output should be escape sequences, and there's no other way around, so you need to modify your output somehow.

One-timer with f-strings may me like:

```
print(f'Value is {OKGREEN if value > 0 else FAIL} {value}')
```

If your case allows this, perfect thing would be encapsulating logic to value class (roughly, if you can use subclass of int/float), so you can provide [`__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) spec with support for coloring.

If you cant, you'll probably end up with wrapper around print.